# How to convert a pytorch Tensor to a numpy array without using detach()?

Tags: python, numpy, types, pytorch, tensor

I am trying to implement an algorithm and I am facing an error in the following block of code :

```
def get_action(self, state):
        state = torch.from_numpy(state).float().unsqueeze(0)
        probs = self.policy_network.forward(Variable(state))
        highest_prob_action = np.random.choice(self.num_actions, p=np.squeeze(probs.numpy())) //This line
        log_prob = torch.log(probs.squeeze(0)[highest_prob_action])
        return highest_prob_action, log_prob
```

To pass in the probability distribution in `np.random.choice`, I used the probs tensor. I know I can use the `detach` function to make it work but I can't use that function because I have to submit this code on an autograder and apparently it returns an error when you use that function.

Is there a way I can do this **without** using the `detach` function?

Here's how the `probs` tensor looks like :

```
tensor([[0.2522, 0.2533, 0.2385, 0.2560]], grad_fn=<SoftmaxBackward>)
```

And I want the final output to be of the type (The values don't mean anything):

```
array([0., 1., 2., 3.], dtype=float32)
```

**To reproduce the error, you can use:**

```
import torch

tensor1 = torch.tensor([1.0,2.0],requires_grad=True)

print(tensor1)
print(type(tensor1))

tensor1 = tensor1.numpy()

print(tensor1)
print(type(tensor1))
```

**What I tried :** As suggested by GoodDeeds in the comments, I tried to use `torch.multinomial` as follows :

```
states.append(state)
            probs = self.policy.forward(Variable(torch.from_numpy(state).float().unsqueeze(0)))
            highest_prob_action = np.random.choice(torch.multinomial(probs, self.num_actions).squeeze(0))
#             highest_prob_action = np.random.choice(self.num_actions, p=np.squeeze(probs.numpy()))
            log_prob = torch.log(probs.squeeze(0)[highest_prob_action])
```

but after some iterations it returns the error:

```
    130             states.append(state)
    131             probs = self.policy.forward(Variable(torch.from_numpy(state).float().unsqueeze(0)))
--> 132             highest_prob_action = np.random.choice(torch.multinomial(probs, self.num_actions).squeeze(0))
    133 #             highest_prob_action = np.random.choice(self.num_actions, p=np.squeeze(probs.numpy()))
    134             log_prob = torch.log(probs.squeeze(0)[highest_prob_action])

RuntimeError: probability tensor contains either `inf`, `nan` or element < 0
```

Comment: No I don't, I set the `probs.requires_grad = False` but it still is giving the same error. Here's the error trace : `132             probs.require_grad = False
--> 133             highest_prob_action = np.random.choice(self.num_actions, p=np.squeeze(probs.numpy()))
    134             log_prob = torch.log(probs.squeeze(0)[highest_prob_action])
    135             action_l.append(highest_prob_action)

RuntimeError: Can't call numpy() on Tensor that requires grad. Use tensor.detach().numpy() instead.`

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I missed that that would not work. In your small example, `tensor1` is a leaf so it works.

Comment: Does this help? https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torch-equivalent-of-numpy-random-choice/16146/14 . You could avoid converting to numpy altogether.

Comment: It does help but I am trying to figure out how to get the action which was returned by it

Comment: Do you know how can I use the `torch.multinomial` in my case to return the action with the highest probability? I tried to use `highest_prob_action = torch.multinomial(probs, self.num_actions)` but it returns a class Tensor error

Comment: Please share full details of the error, perhaps as an edit to the question.

Comment: Did as suggested.